# How to access info in a users app through your app in Obj-C?

Tags: ios

How would you pull info from another app on the users phone. For example if I wanted to take all the emails a user has on their google inbox app or all the transactions from the users chase app and display them, how would I do that?

I understand first you'd need the user to sign in to their app Im sure I can manage how to figure out that. But how would I pull their data to my app and display it?

Comment: you can't access data from other apps.

Comment: You can look into Keychain sharing capabilty. Keychain can store data that the other apps may obtain. But with the examples you stated, I think it is not possible for those apps.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to use an API for the app you are trying to pull information from. Google offers an [API](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/) for Gmail and it is possible to access bank information through an API (see [Is there an API to get bank transaction and bank balance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7269668/is-there-an-api-to-get-bank-transaction-and-bank-balance)).

Although, if you are developing two apps on the same team you can use [Keychain Sharing](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/AddingCapabilities/AddingCapabilities.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012582-CH26-SW15) and [App Groups](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/AddingCapabilities/AddingCapabilities.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012582-CH26-SW61) to share data between your own apps.